# Scammers and private information

Tags: information-gathering

I don't know if its a right place to ask this question, but I could not find any information regarding this and I believe its something to do with security..

I just received a call from unknown number and polite woman asked me some nonsense about the credits and loans. Of course I started asking her questions like what are you on about? She hanged up.. What I found really strange, that they were referring to me by my name. How do they know my name?? Who is selling my information or how do they get that info in first place?

I phoned them back and another person answered the call - male. I asked how do they get my phone and name, and he referred to me with my name again but not answering the question and talking non-stop absolute nonsense. It was a quick call back and he already knew my name. How???

Comment: Any website where you've entered your real name could have given it to them. Any store you've visited and given them your phone number and name (think credit card application) could have sold it to them.

Comment: There are two websites that you can use to see where your information is being used publicly. pipl.com and thatsthem.com some of them tell you where they located your personal information. not all of it is accurate all the time. let me know if that helps

Comment: He knew your name because your phone number was in their database, and was matched to the Caller ID. The trunk software routes the call to the first free operator they have (sometimes *overseas*), and almost certainly also adds details such as "LAST CALLED BY: MARY, Mar 06 2016 18:45 - NO SALE - HARD CUSTOMER" or things like that. On the plus side, chances are that your record in that database now also says 'PRICKLY GUY - DO NOT CALL'.

Comment: I hope they say that as well, but I got the same call 3 times this month and they ask same question and they hang up as soon as I ask anything.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely they got your name, phone number and even more data from a database that has either been compromised or was sold to the highest bidder.

The reason why you reached a male the second time is probably because they sit in a callcenter and you got another person on the line this time.

I would check where you entered data like your name and phone number to prevent something like that in the future, and maybe report the number to the authorities or relevant agency in your country.

But don't expect for your data to disappear, it will probably be forever in some database. Don't worry about that too much though :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah, I know they got from some database, or some companies passed data to them. I mean even ordering pizza is a high risk as the name and number are required to make an order but you never guarantee that your info is in safe hands. It was odd to hear them using my name right after they answered my call. Its like they have some sort of software displaying names of incoming numbers...

Comment: There is a realistic possibility that they have software like that. Yeah, we use tons of services every day on the internet, the chance of your data being sold or stolen at some point is really high.